# Como tratar elementos de um array individualmente?

Tags: php, mysql

Saudações senhores,

Estou tentando projetar um portal onde meus clientes possam visualizar suas faturas, demonstrativos e notas fiscais. Como podem ver está tudo bem amador, mas encontra-se quase pronto para fazer o que preciso. Abaixo segue o código PHP e como fiz para que a informação "fatura" do banco de dados pudesse virar um link (para visualização e download de um arquivo). O problema surge quando tento fazer o mesmo com o objeto "reserva".

Como serão sempre várias reservas por fatura, o MySQL extrai essa informação como uma linha. Eu preciso manipular cada número presente nela, mas tudo o que eu tento só afeta a minha linha como um todo.

Aqui um link para uma pergunta prévia explicando o uso do group_concat nesse caso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549723/how-to-group-data-with-mysql-php

Resultado da página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi('localhost','root','','server');

$sqlFatura = $mysqli->query("SELECT login as NOME,fatura AS  
Fatura, Emissao, Vcto, group_concat(reserva) AS RESERVAS
FROM usuarios INNER JOIN faturas,anexos WHERE 
usuarios.ID=IDlogin AND faturas.ID=IDfatura AND login='". 
mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['login'])."' GROUP BY fatura");


if($sqlFatura->num_rows > 0){
    while($rows = $sqlFatura->fetch_assoc()){
        $fatura = $rows['Fatura'];
        $loc = $fatura .".pdf";
        $stur = $rows['RESERVAS'];
        $emissao = $rows['Emissao'];
        $vcto = $rows['Vcto'];

    echo "<p> Fatura $fatura Emitida dia $emissao Vencimento
    $vcto=><a href='$loc' target='_blank'>DOWNLOAD</a>  ANEXO: $stur<br></p>";

}
}else{
echo "SEM FATURAS.";

}

?>
```

Agradeço de antemão a ajuda e para quaisquer esclarecimentos bastar entrar em contato.

Att,

Comment: Você quer retornar as reservas é quer ter, qual índice como referências ? O id de faturas?

Comment: Sim, exatamente.

Comment: Essa imagem que postou, é o retorno da função que postou ?

Comment: Sim, e o resultado até aqui. Repare que eu consegui tornar cada _fatura_ em um link para o arquivo. Agora eu preciso fazer o mesmo para cada um dos números que seguem o anexo (407685,408475,etc...).

Comment: Bom, mas ao que parece, as informações estão vindo corretamente do banco, o que quer agora é tornar cada uma das reservas um link clicável que aponte para um endereço, é isso ?

Comment: Sim, me parece que é só tratar o php. Infelizmente não estou conseguindo fazer, venho quebrando cabeça tentando com loop, while e for, mas não consigo nenhum resultado sem repetições e ainda assim não clicáveis.

Answer (score 0):

Bem se eu entendi sua dúvida adicione isso ao código e deve funcionar:

```
 echo "<p> Fatura $fatura Emitida dia $emissao Vencimento
       $vcto=><a href='$loc' target='_blank'>DOWNLOAD</a>  
           ANEXO:<a href='url_stur' target='_blank'>$stur</a><br></p>";
```

Comment: Já havia tentado isso. Porém toda a string vira um gigantesco link. Esse problema está sendo bem frustrante.

Comment: Certo, mas qual o objetivo vc deseja então ? Você pode através do css, aplicar uma classe ao elemento link, e retirar o underline com um "text-decoration:none", e deixar o link sublinhado apenas quando o mouse está sobre o link...